# Need 2 raw chopped onions in cole slaw

Tags: onions

Ruined my homemade cole slaw salad with 2 chopped yellow onions...very acidic and bad after taste. Recipe calls for the onions. How do I not ruin the salad the next time with the onions?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you are sure it's the onions that ruined the recipe?  What are the proportions of your recipe?  2 whole onions does sound like a lot, but without knowing how much total you are making, it's hard to say anything certain.

Comment: How about simply reducing the amount of onion if you think it's too much? Tastes differ and recipes can't cater for all.

Answer (score 5):

You don't say how much cole slaw you made with 2 entire chopped onions. I hope it was a *lot*. (I'm not sure I'm familiar with raw chopped onions at all in cole slaw.)

Did this recipe specify yellow onions? or were they perhaps supposed to be one of the "sweet" onion varieties -- Walla Walla, or Vidalia, etc. Those have a lot less bite, and are better to eat raw than the more sulfurous biting types. Maybe next time you might try using them.

Also, if you aren't wedded to this specific recipe, the obvious solution would be include less chopped onion... or even none, if you aren't happy with its contribution to the result.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I not ruin the salad the next time with the onions?

Leave the onions out?

Answer (score 1):

Add the onions last and taste adding just a bit at a time.  A little lemon juice with the onion will tone it down.

Answer (score 0):

Onions can be soaked in cold water and/or rinsed well to remove some of the overpowering flavor.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found the taste of *raw* yellow onions to be a little overpowering. Their strong flavour works well cooked in soups, stews and casseroles though. Sweet white or even red onions (in a purple cabbage slaw) works much better to compliment a slaw's flavour.

One place I once lived at in Canada (many miles from a decent grocery store), I was unable to buy sweet onions. In that case, I'd cut a large yellow onion and just take out some of the centre part to use. Since it's the youngest part of an onion bulb (corm actually), it's also the mildest juiciest part. Cutting it and soaking it in a lightly salted water will help draw out some of the stronger taste too. I'd use less onion than I would a sweet onion and still achieve the taste I wanted.

The rest of the yellow onion wasn't wasted and would usually be used the same day (or next) in some cooked mixture. All that was years back when I could eat onions with impunity. Now I stick to shallots or scallions. Really miss having creamed baby onions. :(